# Automated deployment of JRuby on Rails to Tomcat on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby, capistrano, war

Our team is looking at developing a rails app to be deployed on a Windows server running JRuby fronted by Tomcat.

The ruby code will be compiled to java .class files and then bundled into a .war file using [warbler](http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/).

This will probably be automated by hudson.

We've been using capistrano for "normal" rails deployment and love it but i'm not sure how effective it would be with .war files on Windows.

What is the recommended way of doing "capistrano-like" deployment for .war files on Windows?

Comment: Drop the war file into the Tomcat webapps directory, or use the Ant task, etc. It's a war file; normal deployment mechanisms apply. Not sure if a restart is necessary or not.

Comment: Yep figured that would be the basic idea, but is there a tool to automate that kinda stuff in the java world? or is it a case of manually copying the file or making the build server stick it on a network share? Thanks :)

Comment: Ant and Maven are the canonical automated build tools, along with things like Gradle, Gant, Rant, Buildr, etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can continue to use capistrano, but you have to write your own logic for the deploy script via the capistrano dsl. Capistrano can basically deploy anything, some people use it for PHP for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building your application using Hudson/Jenkins, then it's as easy as adding an extra step to the build process itself.

I added an after-build step:

[X] Deploy war/ear to a container

- **WAR/EAR files**: target/myapp.war
- **Container** : Tomcat 6.x
- **Manager user name**: admin
- **Manager password**: *passwordhere*
- **Tomcat URL**: http://ip.address.here:8080/ (note: don't add any path)

Everytime my build runs successfully, Jenkins deploys (or re-deploys) the new WAR file.

Comment: Great Thanks, I think we're gonna go with for trinidad for deployment now :D